# Question about set: When will $A = (A\setminus B) \cup B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Today , my professor has written a set formula which I don't fully understand: 
$$
A = (A\setminus B) \cup B
$$
Please help me to fill in the missing details for the above, and its proof. My notes are incomplete.

Comment: The claim is true if and only if $A \cap B = B$ (B subset of or equal to A).

Comment: @amWhy. Why not turn this into an answer (with a bit of explanation)?

Comment: @RickDecker Done!

Answer (score 9):

Others have given examples why your posted statement is *not always true*.

I'll expand on a comment I left earlier. ***IF*** one of the premises we are working with is that $B \subseteq A$, then the claim does in fact hold.

In fact claim is true if and only if $A\cap B = B$ (which is equivalent to the premise $B\subseteq A$).  The important thing *here* is whether you see why $$B \subseteq A \implies A = (A \setminus B) \cup B\quad?$$

If we have that $B\subseteq A$, and perform $A \setminus B$, then by definition of set-minus, we take out of $A$ all the elements in $B$ (where $B\subseteq A$), then when we perform $(A\setminus B) \cup B$, by definition of set union, we are putting back *all* the previously removed elements back into A, leaving us with $A$ itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's explanation totally makes sense for the proof my prof was working on. I missed that minor detail about B⊆A, thus he was talking a little bit fast.

Comment: "That is" is misleading since, before it there is an implication while after it there is an equivalence. Both are true but the latter cannot be an explanation of the former.

Comment: You're correct, @Did. I deleted the misleading words. Thank you.

Comment: @Amzoti What is a TU?

Comment: @Ahaan: A "TU" simply means a "Thumb's up", as in an "up vote"! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Ah, nice to know. TU! :D

Answer (score 5):

The claim's false. For example, take

$$A=\{1,2\}\;,\;\;B=\{1,3\}\implies A=\{1,2\}\neq \{2\}\cup\{1,3\}=\{1,2,3\}=(A\setminus B)\cup B\;.$$

Answer (score 3):

$A\setminus B = \left\{x \mid x \in A\text{ and }x\not\in B\right\}$

$A\cup B = \left\{x \mid x \in A\text{ or }\in B\right\}$

---

By the way this formula false.

Take $A=\emptyset$ and $B\not= \emptyset$ (for example $\left\{0\right\}$. Then $\left(A\setminus B\right) = \emptyset$ and so $\left(A\setminus B\right)\cup B = B\not= \emptyset = A$.

Answer (score 3):

$A\setminus B$ is the set of things that are in $A$ but not in $B$. $X\cup Y$ is the set of things that are in $X$, in $Y$, or in both $X$ and $Y$. Thus, the set $(A\setminus B)\cup B$ consists of those things that are in $A$ but not in $B$, and those things that are in $B$. (There are no things in both $A\setminus B$ and $B$: anything in $A\setminus B$ is by definition **not** in $B$.) The equation

$$A=(A\setminus B)\cup B$$

therefore says that the members of $A$ are the things that are in $A$ but not in $B$, and the things that are in $B$. In particular, this says that everything in $B$ belongs to $A$. This certainly isn’t always true, and the other answers have given you some specific counterexamples.

What **is** true is that

$$A=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)\;.$$

$A\cap B$ is the set of things belonging to both $A$ **and** $B$, so this just says that $A$ consists of those things that are in $A$ but not $B$ **and** those things that are in $A$ and in $B$. If $a\in A$, then either $a\in B$, in which case $a\in A\cap B$, or $a\notin B$, in which case $a\in A\setminus B$. Conversely, if $a\in(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$, then either $a\in A\setminus B$, or $a\in A\cap B$, and in both cases $a\in A$.

Note, by the way, that if $B\subset A$, then $A\cap B=B$, and in this special case we do have

$$A=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)=(A\setminus B)\cup B\;.$$

Comment: @Peter: You're welcome.

Comment: @Brain M. Scott: Could you help me so answer this quesrtion http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491186/is-there-a-first-countable-0-dimensonal-locally-compact-lindelof-non-compact

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the topic is $A=(A\cap B)\cup B$ or $A=(A\cup B)\cap B$ (note: this is inequatily modulus)