# Is there a first countable, 0-dimensonal, locally compact, lindelöf, non-compact space?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Is there a  first countable, 0-dimensonal, locally compact, lindelöf, non-compact space in which all non-empty open sets have $\pi$-weight $\mathfrak c$?

It also can be seen [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141927/first-countable-0-dimensonal-locally-compact-lindelof-non-compact-space?noredirect=1#comment366191_141927)
Thanks for your help.

A $\pi$-base for $X$ is a collection $\mathcal V$ of non-empty open sets in $X$ such that if $U$ is any non-empty open set in $X$, then $V \subset U$ for some $V \in \mathcal V$. $\pi w(X)=\min \{|\mathcal V|: \mathcal V \text{ a } \pi \text{-base for } X\} +\omega$.

Comment: It would probably help other people who happen on this question later if you wrote down the definition of $\pi$-weight. As far as I can tell it's not in e.g. Munkres nor is the definition of $\pi$-base in the articles on Wikipedia on [cardinal functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function) and [topological bases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28topology%29).

Comment: @kahen: See the new part!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are such spaces. Here is a way (perhaps not the simplest one) of constructing a space with the properties that you want:

1) Let $Z$ be the Alexandroff duplicate of the Cantor space. All that matters here is that $Z$ is compact, zero-dimensional, first-countable and $d(Z)=\mathfrak{c}$, where $d(\cdot)$ stands for density (i.e. least size of a dense subspace).

2) Let $Y=Z^\omega$ with the product topology. Then $Y$ is still compact, zero-dimensional, first-countable and, by a result of D.B. Motorov, $Y$ is also homogeneous (for this we also use that $Z$ has a dense set of isolated points). Also, not only it is true that $d(Y)=\mathfrak{c}$ (since density can only decrease under continuous maps), but in fact $d(U)=\mathfrak{c}$ for any open $U\subseteq Y$ (here we use compactness and homogeneity of $Y$).

3) Fix $p \in Y$ and let $X=Y \setminus \{p\}$.

We now check that $X$ has all the properties we want. Being a subspace of $Y$, $X$ inherits first-countable and zero-dimensional. Being an open subspace, $X$ also inherits locally compact and "$d(U)=\mathfrak{c}$ for any open $U\subseteq X$". Since $Y$ is compact homogeneous, $p$ is not isolated in $Y$ and therefore $X$ is not compact; however $X$ is Lindelof, being a countable union of compact sets. Finally note that in a first countable space, the $\pi$-weight and the density coincide.

The fact that the $\omega$-th power of a compact zero-dimensional first-countable space with a dense set of isolated points is homogeneous was announced (without proof) by Motorov in "*Zero-dimensional and linearly ordered bicompacta: properties of homogeneity type*". This was improved latter by Dow and Pearl in "*Homogeneity in powers of zero-dimensional first-countable spaces*" where they show that the $\omega$-th power of any zero-dimensional first-countable space is homogeneous.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I'll take some time to read your answer:)

Comment: I think this construction can be simpler. We can pick a point $p$ from $Z$ such that it is not isolated in $Z$ since if every point is isolated then $Z$ cannot be compact. Then $X=Z\setminus\{p\}$ satisfied my all requirements.  Am I right?

Comment: No, if $p$ is a point of $Z$ then $Z \setminus \{p\}$ has isolated points, so it contains open sets of countable $\pi$-weight. That´s why you need first to make the space homogeneous, and that´s the whole point of taking the $\omega$-th power.

Comment: O, thanks! I see! Could you tell me where I can see the aboved result of D.B. Motorov on homegeneous?

Comment: @Paul: I added some references.

Answer (score 0):

[There are more than one](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146).

1. Countable Discrete topology
2. Odd-Even topology
3. Open countable ordinal space
4. Sierpinski's metric space

I would recommend using [Spacebook](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146) for any such queries you might have.

EDIT: These are spaces which satisfy all aforementioned properties except for the $\pi$-weight property. Spacebook does not have that as an option.

Comment: However, do they all have $\pi$-weight $\mathfrak c$?

Comment: @Paul- Not too sure about that. I suppose you could check that property for the spaces listed in the answer.

Comment: None of these meets the requirements. (4) is just (1) with a specific metric. (1), (3) and (4) all have isolated points, which are non-empty open sets of $\pi$-weight $\omega$, not $\mathfrak{c}$. (2) has minimal non-empty open sets $\{2k-1,2k\}$, which also have $\pi$-weight $\omega$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks very much!