# Some observation from an answer to my previous question

Tags: general-topology

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491186/is-there-a-first-countable-0-dimensonal-locally-compact-lindelof-non-compact), I raised this question: Is there a  first countable, 0-dimensonal, locally compact, lindelof, non-compact space in which all non-empty open sets have $\pi$-weight $\mathfrak c$? **Ramiro de la Vega** gives me a good answer as following:

> Yes, there are such spaces. Here is a way (perhaps not the simplest one) of constructing a space with the properties that you want:
>
> 1) Let $Z$ be the Alexandroff duplicate of the Cantor space. All that matters here is that $Z$ is compact, zero-dimensional, first countable and $d(Z)=\mathfrak{c}$, where $d(\cdot)$ stands for density (i.e. least size of a dense subspace).
>
> 2) Let $Y=Z^\omega$ with the product topology. Then $Y$ is still compact, zero-dimensional, first countable and, by a result of D.B. Motorov, $Y$ is also homogeneous (for this we use that $Z$ is zero-dimensional and has a dense set of isolated points). Also, not only it is true that $d(Y)=\mathfrak{c}$ (since density can only decrease under continuous maps), but in fact $d(U)=\mathfrak{c}$ for any open $U\subseteq Y$ (here we use compactness and homogeneity of $Y$).
>
> 3) Fix $p \in Y$ and let $X=Y \setminus \{p\}$.
>
> We now check that $X$ has all the properties we want. Being a subspace of $Y$, $X$ inherits first countable and zero-dimensional. Being an open subspace, $X$ also inherits locally compact and "$d(U)=\mathfrak{c}$ for any open $U\subseteq X$". Since $Y$ is compact homogeneous, $p$ is not isolated in $Y$ and therefore $X$ is not compact; however $X$ is Lindelof, being a countable union of compact sets. Finally note that in a first countable space, the $\pi$-weight and the density coincide.

However I think this construction can be more simpler. My construction is this: Let $Z$ be a compact, zero-dimensional, first countable and $d(Z)=\mathfrak{c}$, where $d(\cdot)$ stands for density (i.e. least size of a dense subspace). We can pick a point $p$ such that it is not isolated in $Z$ since if every point is isolated then $Z$ cannot be compact. Then $X=Z\setminus\{p\}$ satisfied my all requirements. What Ramiro de la Vega does is to make the point $\{p\}$ is isolated. **I think it is not necessary.** Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point for taking the $\omega$-th power is not only to get a non-isolated point but to satisfy your requirement that **all** open sets have big $\pi$-weight (or density). Even if a space has density $\mathfrak{c}$ it could still contain an open set $U$ of smaller (e.g. countable) density; but if the space is compact and homogeneous then, given any open subset $U$, we can cover the space with finitely many copies of $U$ and therefore $U$ must have the same density as the whole space.